# Passing Current userLocation to a mapkit

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on a location-based app at the moment in the swift programming language.

I currently find the users location in the mapview controller using the CoreLocation framework. However, I need the user's current location on the previous view controller. To avoid having to find the users location twice I was hoping I could just find the users location on the previous view controller to the mapview and then just set the map view's 'user's location' variable with this location. However, when I read the documentation it seems that this variable is read-only.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or even whether finding the user's location twice is necessarily a bad thing (maybe swift is already optimised for this purpose snd that is why they made it read only.)?

I appreciate any answers.

Thanks,

Comment: Use mapView.setRegion to set the location coordinate.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go :D